# Does having edit privileges allow me to approve edits from others?

Tags: discussion, reputation, editing, privileges

**Pre-2000 reputation** - Every time I edited a post I needed to await attention before it could be approved. I 100% agree with this rule.

**Post-2000 reputation** - I can edit any post without waiting for approval.

I thought that when I hit the 2000 reputation line, I was also able to accept edits from others (with less than 2000 reputation). If I can, I can't find out how to do this.

If I actually can't, wouldn't it make sense to implement it? Seeing as I can already edit anything, Super User trusts me enough with the content of user's posts and answers. So surely reviewing other's edits would fall under the exact same category?

Am I just whistling Dixie?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can see and approve pending edits from others when you come across a post that has one suggested.

If you want to see the queue of [pending suggested edits](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits), you'll need to break through the 5000 reputation ceiling.

Comment: Why the distinction between falling upon a post with a pending edit and viewing the queue?

Comment: Subjecting yourself to the edit queue is considered a privilege one must reach. More and more of the janitorial work requires a higher level of trust. Or something like that. @max

Comment: I guess I can kind of see where you're coming from. I was just confused by the distinction when the actual ability of editing doesn't change. Thanks for clearing that up.